# solid/react-components: useLDflex() for address

Tags: linked-data, solid

I'm trying to read a user's address from their profile with `useLDflex()` or `useLDflexValue()`.

When I run this:

```
const address = useLDflex(`[${webId}].vcard_hasAddress`)?.toString() || 'loading...';
console.log('address: ', address);
```

Console shows:

```
address:  https://<username>.solidcommunity.net/profile/card#id1234567890,false,
```

I can go to the URL in my browser and is shows the address object but how do I directly access the contents of the address object in my code? I presume there is a function to resolve the address URL and return the contents but can't find it.

Thank you. Any links to reading material on this topic would also be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with/a big fan of LDflex, but I think you might be able to pass e.g. `[address].vcard_locality` to another `useLDflex`, or maybe even directly use `[${webId}].vcard_hasAddress.vcard_locality`?

Comment: That worked for `region` and `locality` but not `country-name`.
Working: `const region = useLDflexValue(`[${webId}].vcard_hasAddress.vcard_region`)?.toString() || 'loading...';`

Can't figure out `country-name`.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug in LDflex not supporting properties with dashes in them - might want to report it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vcard:hasAddress` predicate of a Solid Profile points to an address resource that then has further properties like `vcard:country-name` and `vcard:locality`.

With ldflex you are able to use a dot notation to "chain" your query. So this will get you the address locality:

```
[${webId}].vcard_hasAddress.vcard_locality
```

Instead of dot notation you can also access the properties with square brackets. This will also work with properties, that contain dashes, like country-name:

```
[${webId}].vcard_hasAddress['vcard:country-name']
```

Give it a try [on the LDFlex playground with my WebID](https://solid.github.io/ldflex-playground/#%5Bhttps://angelo.veltens.org/profile/card#me%5D.vcard_hasAddress%5B%27vcard:country-name%27%5D).

If the address is stored in a different document you need to first query the address and then do another query for the address properties:

```
1. [${webId}].vcard_hasAddress
2. [${address}].vcard_locality
```